# R script does not run within Slurm batch job

Tags: r, unix, centos6, slurm, rscript

I am running a script that starts as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
#./geneiase -t static -i mydata.tab
```

If I run the script on my data directly in the command line, it starts without errors or warnings.

But the program is very demanding computationally so I need to submit my jobs to a cluster using a job scheduler called Slurm.

When I write the exact same expression (as in the second paragraph) within the batch job file, and then I submit the job using `sbatch`, it is immediatelly terminated and does not return any error or output that can help me understand the problem.

I think it has to do with having `Rscript` in `$PATH`, but even though I added the directory where `Rscript` is located to `$PATH` by: `PATH=$PATH:path/to/R/build/R-3.4.0/lib64/R/bin`, the problem remains.

Is there a way that I can make Rscript be run in a Slurm batch job?

Comment: I figured out there was a typo in `#SBATCH --workdir=` which is why the job was immediately shot down without output. The job runs after fixing said typo

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to keep the environment of your SLURM script as `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Since you can run your R script from the command line, it likely means the path to R is already included in your $PATH. On the command line, you might already do something like:

```
Rscript ./path-to-script/script
```

To run R from within your SLURM script, it's the same as running from the command line:

```
Rscript ./path-to-script/script
```

Comment: I called the R script within SLURM as you suggested `Rscript ./path-to-script/script`. Unfortunately, the problem remains, even though the same expression works outside SLURM when I type it directly in the command line